# Can I load a flash before my application starts?

Tags: javascript, css, flash, html, web-applications

As the title says it, I want to load a little flash video before my application starts, so people can see my website logo before using my application. Please, any suggestion. btw I make my apps with Javascript, HTML5 and CSS. Thank you.

Comment: [Please don't](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/hated-design.html).

Comment: then why not just have the flash file as the index and redirect users from that page to a new page ?

Comment: Hmm, no, it's just that, I want that once people get on the page to use the app, when it loads, at first you see the flash then it disappear to show the app... Wow, thinking about it now make me think its impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Flash content in one div and App content in another div and toggle **display** property in CSS.